# how to prevent the error multiple definition of main function in c?

Tags: c

I am getting the following error:

In function main:
electionTestsExample.c:(.text+0xf7): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/cc5EeMIa.o:electionTestsExample.c:(.text+0xf7): first defined here

even though I only have one main function
here is my electionTestsExample.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "elections.h"
#include "test_utilities.h"

/*The number of tests*/
#define NUMBER_TESTS 1

static bool deleteOnlyFirstArea (int area_id) {
    return area_id == 1;
}

static bool testElectionRemoveAreas() {
    Election election = electionCreate();
    ASSERT_TEST(electionAddArea(election, 1, "first area") == ELECTION_SUCCESS);
    ASSERT_TEST(electionAddArea(election, 2, "second area") == ELECTION_SUCCESS);

    ASSERT_TEST(electionRemoveAreas(election, deleteOnlyFirstArea) == ELECTION_SUCCESS);
    electionDestroy(election);
    return true;
}

/*The functions for the tests should be added here*/
static bool (*tests[]) (void) = {
                      testElectionRemoveAreas
};

/*The names of the test functions should be added here*/
static const char* testNames[] = {
                           "testElectionRemoveAreas"
};

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        for (int test_idx = 0; test_idx < NUMBER_TESTS; test_idx++) {
              RUN_TEST(tests[test_idx], testNames[test_idx]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Usage: election <test index>\n");
      return 0;
  }

  int test_idx = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  if (test_idx < 1 || test_idx > NUMBER_TESTS) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid test index %d\n", test_idx);
      return 0;
  }

  RUN_TEST(tests[test_idx - 1], testNames[test_idx - 1]);
  return 0;
}
```

here is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
OBJS = electionTests.o election.o electionelem.o vote.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -g
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
electionTests.o : electionTestsExample.c elections.h test_utilities.h
$(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o : elections.c elections.h election_element.h votes.h map.h
$(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
electionelem.o : election_element.c election_element.h votes.h
$(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
vote.o : votes.c votes.h
```

Comment: Maybe there's another definition of `main()` in one of the includes?

Comment: no non of them have a main function

Comment: Show your Make-file or compile instruction.

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was not trying to put a minimal example

Comment: I was trying to show the code so that maybe someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the code, but the answer lies in the build.

The error comes from the linker.  It says `main` is defined twice, *in the same file, at the same place*.  That suggests the file is being linked to itself.

For any function except `main` (which might not be a function), the linker ignores subsequent definitions; that's why you can override standard library functions like **strcpy**(3) or **malloc**(3).  But there can only be one `main`, and two indicates a mistake.

My guess is you have both `electionTestsExample.c` and `electionTestsExample.o` on your command line.